# Dataframe reading and formatting with dates in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date, datetime

Is there a pandas or numpy function that recognizes if a new month has come up from looking at the if the Month(MM) is incremented by 1 with the format `YYYY-MM-DD-TTTT`. So in the sample below I am trying to see if a function can indicate which index the Date goes from October `2015-10-31 23:59:00` to December `2015-11-01 00:00:00`.

Code

```
import pandas as pd

#Getting the input from a csv file 
data= 'input.csv'
#Reverses all the table data values
data1 = data.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
#Getting The date column 
Date = np.array(data1['Date'])
```

Portion of Dates, the 11th index is when it goes from October to November

```
['2015-10-31 23:50:00' '2015-10-31 23:51:00' '2015-10-31 23:52:00'
 '2015-10-31 23:53:00' '2015-10-31 23:54:00' '2015-10-31 23:55:00'
 '2015-10-31 23:56:00' '2015-10-31 23:57:00' '2015-10-31 23:58:00'
 '2015-10-31 23:59:00' '2015-11-01 00:00:00' '2015-11-01 00:01:00'
 '2015-11-01 00:02:00' '2015-11-01 00:03:00' '2015-11-01 00:04:00'
```

Expected Output

```
At the 11th index the Month changes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're going to likely reach a point where you want to identify where the month changes again, I'm providing a solution for multiple month changes. This uses pandas' `.diff()`, reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html

```
# first convert strings to datetime
data1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data1['Date'])

month_changes = data1.loc[np.where(data1['Date'].dt.month.diff().gt(0))].index.tolist()

for month_change in month_changes:
    print(f'At the {month_change + 1}th index the month changes')
```

Comment: It is giving me an error `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
`

Comment: Please see edited answer for the way to convert the strings into datetimes.

Comment: Thank you it works, it is a little bit slow would there be anyway I could accelerate the pandas code, since i am working with a very large dataframe?

Comment: Ah, I'm unable to think of anything to speed it up right now; but I'll keep thinking, and update the answer if I come up with any optimisation(s).

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, if you cant find anything, thats okay. The function you have given is also more than enough, I appreciate it.